# What is nextJS getStaticPaths performance?

Tags: next.js

I want to create a bunch of static pages, but I am not sure that next.js is up to it. Gatsby, with default settings, drops dead.
I have 3 types of data I want to show respectively generating 15 / 50 / 150 k of pages
Later one (150k), I expect,to be rebuild each day.
Will nextJS handle that? Are there any time estimates I can take a look?

If I understand correctly

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // Call an external API endpoint to get cities
    const res = await fetch('https://.../cities')
    const cities = await res.json()
  
    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on cities
    const paths = cities.map((post) => ({
      params: { id: post.id },
    }))
  
    // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
    // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
    return { paths, fallback: false }
  }
```

instead of doing one call, I will have to call fetch repeatedly until I will have all the data in one variable, but I am a bit afraid that everything will crash.
What are your thoughts, guys?

**UPD**
https://static-tweet.now.sh/ that should be my answer

Comment: "I want to create a bunch of static pages, but I am not sure that next.js is up to it." - why don't you simply test?

Comment: That is what I am doing. In the meantime I have decided to ask the community :)

Comment: That link didn't answer your question. I am also interested in an answer too!